# After hiding the bottomBorder in My header while navigating it shows the bottom line

Tags: react-native, stylesheet, react-native-navigation

I have hidded my header borderBottom line. It gets hide and works fine with the below code.

But while navigating back it shows the border line.  How can I remove this while back navigation also

```
headerStyle: { 
  backgroundColor: '#fff',
  borderBottomWidth: 0, 
  borderColor:'transparent', 
  elevation: 0, 
  shadowColor: 'transparent', 
  shadowOpacity: 0,
}
```

[image]

Comment: can you share an expo snack so that we can check there

Answer (score 0):

Try this : `borderBottom: none!important;`

Comment: Whether it is applicable for styleSheet?

Comment: Try like this since i am not able to test now: `borderBottom: 'none',` or perhaps you may have another class overriding your css.